# Make inventory that receives purchased items from the shop system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make *items* purchased from my game shop, like decoration, to go to the *inventory* after I purchase them.

[image: Shop system]

I have created a shop system with purchase buttons and stuff, but I don't know how to make inventory receive the items. These are the scripts I have for the shop and the inventory:

#### Shop system

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[,] shopItems = new int[9, 9];
    public float coins;
    public Text CoinsTXT;


    void Start()
    {
        CoinsTXT.text = "" + coins.ToString();

        //ID's
        shopItems[1, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[1, 2] = 2;
        shopItems[1, 3] = 3;
        shopItems[1, 4] = 4;
        shopItems[1, 5] = 5;
        shopItems[1, 6] = 6;
        shopItems[1, 7] = 7;
        shopItems[1, 8] = 8;

        //Price
        shopItems[2, 1] = 10;
        shopItems[2, 2] = 20;
        shopItems[2, 3] = 30;
        shopItems[2, 4] = 40;
        shopItems[2, 5] = 50;
        shopItems[2, 6] = 65;
        shopItems[2, 7] = 110;
        shopItems[2, 8] = 150;

    }


    public void Buy()
    {
        GameObject ButtonRef = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Event").GetComponent<EventSystem>().currentSelectedGameObject;

        if (coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])
        {
            coins -= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID];
            CoinsTXT.text = "Coins:" + coins.ToString();
        }


    }
}
```

#### Inventory system

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory {

    private List<Item> itemList;

    public Inventory()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();

        Debug.Log("Inventory");
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        itemList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

What should I add to make it receive the purchased items?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameEvents gameEvents;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameEvents = this;
    }

    public event Action<int> onItemPurchase;

    public void ItemPurchaseMade(Item int)
    {
        if (onItemPurchase != null)
        {
            onItemPurchase(int);
        }
    }
}
```

I got these errors:

> Assets\GameEvents.cs(17,39): error CS1001: Identifier expected
>
> Assets\GameEvents.cs(17,39): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
>
> Assets\GameEvents.cs(17,42): error CS1001: Identifier expected
>
> Assets\GameEvents.cs(21,28): error CS1525: Invalid expression term
> 'int'

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameEvents gameEvents;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameEvents = this;
    }

    public event Action<int> onItemPurchase;

    public void ItemPurchaseMade(int itemId)
    {
        if (onItemPurchase != null)
        {
            onItemPurchase(itemId);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors I got after editing to itemId:

> Assets\Scripts\GameEvents.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace
> '' already contains a definition for 'GameEvents'
>
> Assets\Scripts\GameEvents.cs(15,25): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\GameEvents.cs(17,34): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Inventory.cs(20,25): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\GameEvents.cs(10,18): error CS0111: Type 'GameEvents'
> already defines a member called 'Awake' with the same parameter types
>
> Assets\Scripts\Inventory.cs(8,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace
> name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

Comment: The OP's actions is being discussed on [the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419866/2821954).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use events to make your scripts "communicate" independently.

First you need the gameevents. Make sure you have the **script on a gameobject in your scene**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameEvents gameEvents;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameEvents = this;
    }

    public event Action<Item> onItemPurchase;

    public void ItemPurchaseMade(Item item)
    {
        if(onItemPurchase != null)
        {
            onItemPurchase(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then include the trigger in your buy method:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[,] shopItems = new int[9, 9];
    public float coins;
    public Text CoinsTXT;


    void Start()
    {
        CoinsTXT.text = "" + coins.ToString();

        //ID's
        shopItems[1, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[1, 2] = 2;
        shopItems[1, 3] = 3;
        shopItems[1, 4] = 4;
        shopItems[1, 5] = 5;
        shopItems[1, 6] = 6;
        shopItems[1, 7] = 7;
        shopItems[1, 8] = 8;

        //Price
        shopItems[2, 1] = 10;
        shopItems[2, 2] = 20;
        shopItems[2, 3] = 30;
        shopItems[2, 4] = 40;
        shopItems[2, 5] = 50;
        shopItems[2, 6] = 65;
        shopItems[2, 7] = 110;
        shopItems[2, 8] = 150;

    }


    public void Buy()
    {
        GameObject ButtonRef = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Event").GetComponent<EventSystem>().currentSelectedGameObject;

        if (coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])
        {
            coins -= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID];
            CoinsTXT.text = "Coins:" + coins.ToString();

            Item yourItem = Item() //get your Item from ID

            GameEvents.gameEvents.ItemPurchaseMade(yourItem);
        }


    }
}
```

Then listen to the event from your inventory class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory {

    private List<Item> itemList;

    public Inventory()
    {

        GameEvents.gameEvents.onItemPurchase += AddItem;

        itemList = new List<Item>();

        Debug.Log("Inventory");
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        itemList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It is unclear where you get the item by their ids from. That is why I left that part out. As an alternative, you could pass the itemId though the events and get the item in the inventory class.

Comment: I have a script called Item and it has item IDs

Comment: Then you can get the Item by Id in the buy method and pass it through the event.

Comment: how do i pass the ItemID through the events as an alternative?

Comment: You change the event to  public event Action<int> onItemPurchase; and change all parameter from Item to int

Comment: like this? check the Edit i did on the this question. i replaced the item with int i have some errors.

Comment: public void ItemPurchaseMade(int itemId) is correct

Comment: thank you now only one error in line 21 says Assets\GameEvents.cs(21,28): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'int'

Comment: I dont know which line that is but i assume you didnt change to onItemPurchase(itemId); ?

Comment: I added a second edit to what i edited and the errors i got after i changed it to itemId

Comment: According to your coding style i would recommend you to learn the basics first instead of posting a question for every problem you run into. It will give you a deeper understanding of coding. And will save you a lot of time on StackOverflow. There are lots of great tutorials on e.g. youtube espacially for unity